# conditionally passing data in express js route

Tags: node.js, express

Express js question here.
I want to check if {id} is passed in the request. If id is passed then show post/info related to id, otherwise, show all posts.

I tried

```
const posts = [{},{}]    
app.get('/posts/:id',(req,res)=>{
        if(!req.params.id){
          return res.render('posts')
        }
    else{
          const fpost = posts.filter((post)=>{
          return post.id == req.params.id
        })[0]
        res.render('posts',{filterdPost:fpost})
        }

 })
```

but it failed when tried to get posts/ without the id. Do I have to create a separate route for posts only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *?* Operator to make the parameters as optional.

```
/post/:id?
```